# HTML Emails Sending in Plain Text? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, email

Okay okay, I know there are a million of these threads, but I did my best to look through them and could not find one that actually solved the problem for me.  Any help is greatly appreciated, as depending on the browser it either hides the whole thing or shows it in plain text.

Here's what I'm using:

```
$headers = 'From: coupons@madisoncoupons.com\r\n';
$headers .= 'Reply-To: coupons@madisoncoupons.com\r\n';
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1';
mail($email,$subject,$content,$headers);
```

$content starts and ends with html and body tags, with a style tag in the beginning of the body with some CSS in it.

Comment: What's the $content variable?

Comment: try $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

Comment: @MikeBarwick It's just the contents of the email.  I updated the post a bit.

Comment: Read up on mail headers, many examples to choose from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Gotta yeah. the 1 answer is likely the problem. Good luck!

Comment: @GirishGowda Thanks, I'm trying that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the correct quotes. `"\r\n"` and `'\r\n'` are two completely different things.

Read up on how [PHP handles strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) if you're rusty.

Comment: Ahhh, lovely.  I'll test that out right now...I do actually know how PHP handles strings, but I've never really had use for \r and \n in the past and just assumed it was something handled by the browser.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as @tadman said above, you have to modify your headers to the following

```
$headers = 'From: coupons@madisoncoupons.com' ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: coupons@madisoncoupons.com' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Use this   




   // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <info@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    mail($email,$subject,$content,$headers);
```